# Issue with the SQL query while doing string_split

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying with this query

```
select * 
from mytable
JOIN STRING_SPLIT('109,110,111,114',',')
ON value = (select col1 from mytable WHERE id = 52);
```

I am getting empty results, why it is not matching? The col1 has the values as comma separated stored.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `on` clause, no subquery:

```
select t.* 
from mytable t JOIN 
     STRING_SPLIT('109,110,111,114',',') s
     on s.value = t.col
where t.id = 52;
```

Comment: @GMX . . . Given that your question has no sample data or desired results, it is extremely vague to say this returns "wrong" results.  That statement in itself suggests that it does return results, which means that it addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `STRING_SPLIT` at all here? Wouldn't this be easier with a `IN`?

```
SELECT MT.* --This should really be a list of columns
FROM dbo.MyTable MT
WHERE MT.id = 52
  AND MT.col1 IN (109,110,111,114); --Assumes that col1 is an int
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `apply` :

```
select *
from mytable mt cross apply
     string_split(mt.col1, ',') mt1 inner join
     string_split('109,110,111,114',',') spt
     on spt.value = mt1.col1
where mt.id = 52;
```